# Overlap graph on image using coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I have two lists of coordinates: first for x-coordinates and second for y-coordinates. I trying to use them as nodes of a graph.

```
import networkx as nx
list_of_coordinates_x = list(4.5 , 4, 67, 578, 68) #random numbers
list_of_coordinates_y = list(6.7, 3, 12, 45.555, 692)

G=nx.MultiGraph()
for i in range(len(list_of_coordinates_x)):
    G.add_node(i, x = list_of_coordinates_x[i], y = list_of_coordinates_y[i])
    if i > 0:
       G.add_edge(i-1,i)

nx.draw(G,node_size=10,with_labels=False)
```

But the all graphs that I have by this way looks like sets of nodes put on the plane randomly. How can I fixate them by my coordinates on the image? And how can I use my own 1680x1050 .jpg file for that? 
After using the answer on the first part of the question, I have this graph:

[image: I have this graph]

But I want to put it on a picture like this:

[image: But I want to put it on a picture like this]

Comment: What criteria are you following to set edges between nodes? Just consecutive nodes?

Comment: @yatu I make them between nodes with consecutive indices. Just because my nodes represent coordinates of some moving point on the plot and the edges --- transitions between them in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you need to set the node positions as attributes, and just use a placeholder as node name. So one approach could be to just `enumerate` the nodes in the order they appear, and follow the same logic as yours, but adding the zipped coordinate elements as `pos` attributes:

```
x = [4.5 , 420, 67, 620, 68]
y = [6.7, 68, 56, 231, 380]

G = nx.DiGraph()
coords = list(zip(x,y))
for node, coo in enumerate(coords, start=1):
    G.add_node(node, pos=coo)
    if node<len(coords):
        G.add_edge(node, node+1)
```

Then you could create a dictionary as `node:(x,y)` which is the format that `pos` in `nx.draw` is expecting, and the nodes are in this way located on the specified coordinates:

```
nodes = G.nodes(data=True)
pos = {node:attr['pos'] for node, attr in nodes}
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
nx.draw(G,
        nodelist=nodelist,
        pos=pos,
        node_size=500,
        node_color='orange')
```

[image]

In order to overlap the graph on an existing image you have to make sure that they both share the same `extent`. This is nicely explained [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/layer_images.html):

> When layering multiple images, the images need to have the same
>    extent.  This does not mean they need to have the same shape, but
>    they both need to render to the same coordinate system determined by
>    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax

In order to do so, you can enforce a certain extent to both the graph coordinates and the image. This value will depend on the image size, so you'll have to adjust the extent of both the graph and image to the actual size of the image. I'll use a sample image from `klearn.datasets.load_sample_image` as an example, but for your own image you can just load it with `matplotlib.image.imread('my_image.jpg')`.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
img = load_sample_image('flower.jpg')

x = [4.5 , 420, 67, 620, 68]
y = [6.7, 68, 56, 231, 380]

y_lim, x_lim = img.shape[:-1]
extent = 0, x_lim, 0, y_lim

G = nx.DiGraph()
coords = list(zip(x,y))
for node, coo in enumerate(coords, start=1):
    G.add_node(node, pos=coo)
    if node<len(coords):
        G.add_edge(node, node+1)

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False, figsize=(10,19))

plt.imshow(img, extent=extent, interpolation='nearest')

nodes = G.nodes(data=True)
pos = {node:attr['pos'] for node, attr in nodes}
nx.draw(G,
        nodelist=nodelist,
        pos=pos,
        node_size=200,
        edge_color='w',
        width=4,
        extent=extent,
        node_color='orange',
       interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is that “zipped coordinates”?

Comment: Its just using `zip` on the lists. `zip` aggregates multiple iterables into tuples. So in this case it would give `(x0,y0),(x1,y1),...` @Arsenii

Comment: I am sorry, but I stacked here: `pos = {node:attr['pos'] for node, attr in nodes}` what is going on at this moment? What does `attr['pos']` mean?

Comment: Have a look at what `G.nodes(data=True)` gives. With that, you're creating a dictionary by iterating over the nodes and their attributes. `attr['pos']` is accessing the `pos` key in the attribute dictionary of the node @Arsenii

Comment: Yep, thank you, it works) 
Maybe you know, how can I use concrete picture for drawing this graph on it? Something like the photo, where I can place my nodes in points with similar pixel coordinates.

Comment: Updated the answer @Arsenii , see if that solves it for you

Comment: Updated the question with examples about what I mean.. 
I have a graph (like in post), but I want to draw it on the picture, that I download from my PC. I can do it in matplotlib, but don't know, how to do it in networkx

Comment: Hopefully this resembles more what you want @Arsenii

Comment: oh, thank you very much, it looks great) I am going to use it

Comment: Hi, it seems "extent" is no longer an argument in networkx?