# Plotting a scatter plot on an image Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, mapping

I have plotted some data that are defined by specific coordinates and a value.

I have plotted this with a scatterplot, and would now like to plot this on top of an image, to reflect where the data points are located.
I have tried to use `matplotlib.image` and import `img` to be able to show the image. Unfortunately, the image of my location does not match up with the data completely (due to stretching, I believe).

When I edit the `extent` Python either edits out some of the image, instead of moving my data. I would like to be able to move the image/crop it to fit with the data or use some sort of package to load in a map (as I have the coordinates). This needs to show a local stream in Denmark.

`x` and `y` are our coordinates (lat, lon) and `z` is the value each coordinate have.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.scatter(x,y, cmap = 'gist_heat' ,s=100,c=z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylim(np.min(y),np.max(y))
plt.xlim(np.min(x),np.max(x))

img = plt.imread("grindsted4_sattelit.png")
ext = [np.min(x),np.max(x), np.min(y), np.max(y)]
plt.imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=ext)

aspect=img.shape[0]/float(img.shape[1])*((ext[1]-ext[0])/(ext[3]-ext[2]))
plt.gca().set_aspect(aspect)

plt.show()
```

[image: The plot are the colored dots, and the black and white dots are my coordinates in Google Earth]
The plot are the colored dots, and the black and white dots are my coordinates in Google Earth.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried normalizing the data to fit the image scale? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61674901/9698684

Comment: @yatu I'm not sure how the suggested link is in relation to this, as I wish to keep the coordinates on my axis. But please let me know if I don't completely understand the link! :)

Comment: Also, must this be in Python?  There are tools (gpsbabel, viking) that will allow you to create a gpx file (from a series of latitude/longitude), and overlay it on a map/satellite image.